# How to publish a Workflow Template in Netsuite?

Tags: templates, workflow, publish, netsuite

can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to publish workflow template in Netsuite.

I've search their help but could not find any substantial documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SuiteBundler to group customizations including workflows, custom fields, related saves searches, scripts, etc. into a single package.  That package can be installed like an application.  You can publish those bundles with NetSuite and set them as private for you only, shared with specific partners, or public.

To get to the Bundle Builder go to Customization > SuiteBundler > Create Bundle (Administrator).

If you don't see it with administrator access, first enable the "Create Bundles With SuiteBundler" feature at Setup > Company > Setup Tasks > Enable Features.

Also check out the SuiteAnswer called "Bundling a Workflow" (Answer Id: 40506).

It's a really cool feature!